# How to register a virtual pageview in Google Analytics (for single-page apps)

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) to track navigation through a single page web app.

The URL of the app is, for example: `www.domain.com/myapp`

Every time the view changes, I send execute the snippet below:

```
ga('send', 'pageview','view_'+current_view);
```

`current_view` is the ID of the view being displayed on the screen.

I want to track how many times each view is visited. The report should look something like this:

> ======================
>
> View Name | Unique Pageview
>
> /view_1 | 20
>
> /view_2 | 30
>
> ======================

GA only has documentation on how send pageview data, but nothing about how to put a report together. How can I view this pageview data in GA?

Comment: You look in the regular Page report (or use the Page dimension, etc.) same as regular pages. Creating a "virtual" page just means that you overwrite the default page name with whatever value you want.

Answer (score 1):

This code will register a pageview in Google Analytics:

`ga('send', 'pageview','view_'+current_view);`

These pageview events are no different than normal pageviews and will show up in all reports that allow you to view pages viewed (e.g. Behavior > Site Overview > All Pages). That being said, if you're using the regular (aka free) version of Google Analytics, you will only see these pageviews in your reports after 12am (your time zone).

On the other hand, if you'd like to perform some testing to make sure the 'pageview' events are actually being registered, you can check out the "Real Time" report (i.e. Real Time > Overview).

If, when testing, you send a 'pageview' event that isn't registered in the "Real Time" report, you'll know there's a problem sending the data along to Google Analytics. In this case, I'd suggest you make sure `current_view` is actually a string. Also, keep in mind that you can send more information than just the page url like so:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': url,'title': title});
```

The above snippet comes directly from a production single-page app I worked on a couple months back. You can check out all the extra data you can send along to Google Analytics at the [analytics.js API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/).

If you're interested in generating **custom** reports, you should check out [this page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en). You should look [here](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/expert-google-analytics-reports/) for some examples of the sorts of reports you can make, and look [here](http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/create-google-analytics-custom-report-ht) for even more information on generating reports.